# qInstallMessageHandler pointer to external lib method

Tags: c++, qt

** I followed : http://www.qt-coding.com/2013/08/06/tip-of-the-day-redirect-qdebug-to-a-file/

I have created a method:

```
MyLogging(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg);
```

And it is located in an external lib (I created) for my main project.

When I do the following:

```
qInstallMessageHandler(MyLib::MyLogging);
```

the compiler says it cannot to the conversion:

`error: C2664: 'QtMessageHandler qInstallMessageHandler(QtMessageHandler)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'void (__cdecl MyLib::* )(QtMsgType,const QMessageLogContext &,const QString &)' to 'QtMessageHandler` There is no context in which this conversion is possible'

But if I move my MyLogging method inline with the main.cpp, everything works.

I'm following why this is the case. Any help in understanding this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Member functions(methods) are quite different from regular ones. They need to know which object are they called for (`this` pointer). So to fix it make `MyLogging` a global function or a static member function.

Note: There is also `mem_fn` in `C++11` that can solve the above problem, but `qInstallMessageHandler` needs a function pointer, when `mem_fn` creates wrapper objects. Maybe this will change in later Qt versions.

Comment: Ah, ok. C++ is missing some things that are easier in C#/Java.  Thanks @nazar554